# Vagrantfile:10:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: magento, rubygems, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

Setting up vagrant/virtualbox for Magento. I'm having problem with undefined method. I just started with all of this, still learning, understanding how this works.

On vagrant up I'm getting this error:

```
/Vagrantfile:10:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `block in load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in `vagrantfile'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:486:in `host'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:208:in `block in action_runner'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:473:in `hook'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:722:in `unload'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant:177:in `<main>'
```

This is my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

require 'yaml'
vagrantConfig = YAML.load_file 'Vagrantfile.config.yml'
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/vivid64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: vagrantConfig['ip']

  config.vm.synced_folder vagrantConfig['synced_folder']['host_path'],
  vagrantConfig['synced_folder']['guest_path'], 
  owner:"vagrant", 
  group: "www-data", 
  mount_options:["dmode=775, fmode=664"]

  # VirtualBox specific settings
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = false
    vb.memory = "2048"
    vb.cpus = 2
  end

config.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.gitconfig", destination: ".gitconfig"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt-get update"

config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt-get -y install php5 php5-dev php5-curl php5-imagick php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-mhash php5-mysql php5-xdebug php5-intl php5-xsl"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo php5enmod mcrypt"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo \"xdebug.max_nesting_level=200\" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt-get -y install phpunit"

config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password #{vagrantConfig['mysql']['password']}'"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password #{vagrantConfig['mysql']['password']}'"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo service mysql start"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults"

config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt-get -y install apache2"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo update-rc.d apache2 defaults"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo service apache2 start"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo a2enmod rewrite"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo awk '/<Directory \\/>/,/AllowOverride None/{sub(\"None\", \"All\",$0)}{print}' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf > /tmp/tmp.apache2.conf"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo mv /tmp/tmp.apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo awk '/<Directory \\/var\\/www\\/>/,/AllowOverride None/{sub(\"None\", \"All\",$0)}{print}' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf > /tmp/tmp.apache2.conf"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo mv /tmp/tmp.apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo service apache2 stop"

config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo rm -Rf /var/www/html"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo ln -s #{vagrantConfig['synced_folder']['guest_path']} /var/www/html"

config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "composer clearcache"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo '{\"http-basic\": {\"repo.magento.com\": {\"username\": \"#{vagrantConfig ['http_basic']['repo_magento_com']['username']}\",\"password\": \"#{vagrantConfig['http_basic']['repo_magento_com']['password']} \"}}, \"github-oauth\": {\"github.com\": \"#{vagrantConfig['github_oauth']['github_com']}\"}}' >> /root/.composer/auth.json"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "composer create-project -- repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project- community-edition /var/www/html/"

config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo mysql -- user=#{vagrantConfig['mysql']['username']} -- password=#{vagrantConfig['mysql']['password']} -e \"CREATE DATABASE #{vagrantConfig['magento']['db_name']};\""

config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo php /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:install --base- url=\"#{vagrantConfig['magento']['base_url']}\" --db- host=\"#{vagrantConfig['mysql']['host']}\" --db- user=\"#{vagrantConfig['mysql']['username']}\" --db- password=\"#{vagrantConfig['mysql']['password']}\" --db- name=\"#{vagrantConfig['magento']['db_name']}\" --admin- firstname=\"#{vagrantConfig['magento']['admin_firstname']}\" -- admin-lastname=\"#{vagrantConfig['magento']['admin_lastname']}\" --admin-email=\"#{vagrantConfig['magento']['admin_email']}\" -- admin-user=\"#{vagrantConfig['magento']['admin_user']}\" -- admin-password=\"#{vagrantConfig['magento']['admin_password']}\" --backend- frontname=\"#{vagrantConfig['magento']['backend_frontname']}\" - -language=\"#{vagrantConfig['magento']['language']}\" -- currency=\"#{vagrantConfig['magento']['currency']}\" -- timezone=\"#{vagrantConfig['magento']['timezone']}\""
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo php /var/www/html/bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo php /var/www/html/bin/magento cache:disable"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo php /var/www/html/bin/magento cache:flush"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo php /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:performance:generate-fixtures /var/www/html/setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/small.xml"

end
```

Comment: welcome to SO - past the whole vagrantfile, how is vagrantConfig defined (add the config part of the file if needed) ? add `p vagrantConfig['synced_folder']` just above to print value but its probably null

Comment: When I add p vagrantConfig I get this {"host_path"=>"/Users/User/www/Magento-Box", "guest_path"=>"/vagrant-Magento-Box/"}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do

```
config.vm.synced_folder "#{vagrantConfig['synced_folder']['host_path']}", "#{vagrantConfig['synced_folder']['guest_path']}"
```